# How to remove more than one whitespace character from HTML?

Tags: html, coldfusion, whitespace, coldfusion-8

I want to remove extra whitespace which is coming from the user end, but I can't predict the format of the HTML.

For example:

```
<p> It's interesting that you would try cfsetting, since nothing in it's
documentation would indicate that it would do what you are asking.
Unless of course you were mis-reading what "enableCFoutputOnly" is
supposed to do.


</p>



<p>



It's interesting that you would try cfsetting, since nothing in it's
documentation would indicate that it would do what you are asking.
Unless of course you were mis-reading what "enableCFoutputOnly" is
supposed to do.</p>
```

Please guide me on how to remove more than one whitespace character from HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex to replace any cases of multiple whitespace characters with a single space by looping over the result until no more multiple whitespace occurances exist:

```
lastTry = "<p>   lots of space    </p>";
nextTry = rereplace(lastTry,"\s\s", " ", "all");
while(nextTry != lastTry) {
  lastTry = nextTry;
  nextTry = REReplace(lastTry,"\s\s", " ", "all");
}
```

Tested working in CF10.

Comment: That's a very long-winded way of doing it! Quickest way is probably: `input.replaceAll('\s\s+',' ')`

Or, to avoid replacing newlines with spaces, could also do: `input.replaceAll('(\s)\s+','$1')` (i.e. condense all whitespace to the first one found in each chain).

Comment: Of course, all of these will modify content inside pre/etc - if stuff like that matters then a proper HTML parser is a better way to approach this, especially since there's a good chance of already having a 'tidy' method to deal with exactly this situation.

Comment: side note: since the OP has explicitly labelled the question as CF8, testing with CF10 is kinda redundant (however, everything here is simple enough to should work fine from CF7 onwards.)

Comment: ah, I think that input.replaceAll('(\s)\s+','$1') is a better solution. Why not put that as a separate answer?

Comment: re: side note: "everything here is simple enough to should work fine from CF7 onwards" -- exactly.

Comment: If I'd just added a new answer you wouldn't have been notified. :)  Plus I'd prefer something that allowed `HtmlParser.parse(input).format()` to not break pre-formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<cfscript>
  string function stripCRLFAndMultipleSpaces(required string theString) {
    local.result = trim(rereplace(trim(arguments.theString), "([#Chr(09)#-#Chr(30)#])", " ", "all"));
    local.result = trim(rereplace(local.result, "\s{2,}", " ", "all"));
    return local.result;
  }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: All my comments on Russ's answer apply here too - this will break formatting of `pre` tags and since it converts newlines to spaces has potential to break JavaScript functionality too.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to do it thru code out of total lazyness

> => http://jsbeautifier.org/

if you want to do it by code then a regex would be another option